# Add clear form and hide div when button clicked

Tags: javascript

I have had this issue before but people keep getting my question misunderstood. I will try again. I have a bootstrat button that when clicked javascript sends the form using ajax. It works fine but I cannot add anything to clear the form and then hide the div. I have code that does work but it sends the form twice for some reason(not included but can if you wish)? Sorry to repost similar question but people keep giving me the same code that simply does not work. I think it has something to do with it being a button type?

The JS code is :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-finish').on('click', function() {

        // Add text 'loading...' right after clicking on the submit button. 
        $('.output_message').text('Processing...'); 

        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            method: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(result){
                if (result == 'success'){
                    $('.output_message').text('Message Sent!');

                } else {
                    $('.output_message').text('Error Sending email!');
                }
            }
        });

        // Prevent default submission of the form after clicking on the submit button. 
        return false;

    });
});
```

And the button is :

```
<button name ='send' value="Send" type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Finish</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that works making fake AJAX request. It replaces output_message with Processing... and replaces with Message Sent! once complete.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn-finish').on('click', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    // Add text 'loading...' right after clicking on the submit button. 
    $('.output_message').text('Processing...');

    var form = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("fake ajax");
      $('.output_message').text('Message Sent!');
      // This will clear out form field values.
      // resetForm($('#myform')); // by id, recommended
      
      // This will hide your element
      // $('#myform').hide();
    }, 5000);

  });
});

function resetForm($form) {
    $form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
    $form.find('input:radio, input:checkbox')
         .removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="btn-finish" name='send' value="Send" type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Finish</button>
<div class="output_message"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks but don`t uderstand answer, my code already works but I want it to clear the form and hide the div upon success!!

Comment: You write that code in success method of your AJAX code. Clear method and hide div code. Is that what you are missing?

Comment: I have the code ut it doesnt work with the method i am trying

Comment: updated code to reset form fields and hide your form. You will need to replace that with your form's ID

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reset form script from w3schools.com that should work

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-finish').on('click', function() {

```
    // Add text 'loading...' right after clicking on the submit button. 
    $('.output_message').text('Processing...'); 

    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        method: form.attr('method'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(result){
            if (result == 'success'){
             document.getElementById(form.attr('id')).reset();
             document.getElementById(form.attr('id')).style.display="none";
                $('.output_message').text('Message Sent!');

            } else {
                $('.output_message').text('Error Sending email!');
            }
        }
    });

    // Prevent default submission of the form after clicking on the submit button. 
    return false;

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(result){
                if (result == 'success'){
                    $('.output_message').text('Message Sent!');
                    //code to clear form and hide div comes here
                    $("#divid").hide();
                } else {
                    $('.output_message').text('Error Sending email!');
                }
            },
complete: function(){
         //code to clear form and hide div comes here
                $("#divid").hide();
         }
```

try placing the code to hide and clear the form as mentioned above in success. If ajax response is success or error, by default if you want to hide then use the code in complete function as above.Post your comments.